# C++ Data Structure: Can't display string corresponding to the largest number

Tags: c++

My first C++ class coming from a basic Java class. This class is a more advanced C++ programming class about Data Structures. I don't know the basics of C++, only a little basics of Java.

Assignment is to :

-get 3 user inputs of states and their population (done).

-Get the most populated (biggest of three) and post it. (1/2)

I am able to get the highest number... but I'm not sure on the syntax on how to post it with the corresponding string (state).

I know this is some kind of array using struct, but I dont know how to post st.title

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;

    struct states_t {
        string statename;
        int population;
    } state[3];



    int main()
    {
        string mystr;
        int n;

        for (n = 0; n<3; n++)
        {
            cout << "Enter state name: ";
            getline(cin, state[n].statename);
            cout << "Enter population: ";
            getline(cin, mystr);
            stringstream(mystr) >> state[n].population;
        }

        cout << "\nYou have entered these movies:\n";
        for (n = 0; n < 3; n++)
            cout << state[n].statename << "\n" << state[n].population << "\n";
        return 0;


    }
```

==== UPDATED CODE WITH LARGEST POPULATION ====

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct states_t {
    string statename;
    int population;
} state[3];



int main()
{
    string mystr;
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n<3; n++)
    {
        cout << "Enter state name: ";
        getline(cin, state[n].statename);
        cout << "Enter population: ";
        getline(cin, mystr);
        stringstream(mystr) >> state[n].population;
    }

    cout << "\nYou have entered these states:\n";
    for (n = 0; n < 3; n++)
        cout << state[n].statename << " " << state[n].population << "\n" << "\n";





    if ((state[0].population >= state[1].population) && (state[0].population >= state[2].population))
        cout << "The most populous state you entered is: " << state[0].statename << " with a population of " << state[0].population << "\n";
    else if ((state[1].population >= state[0].population) && (state[1].population >= state[2].population))
        cout << "The most populous state you entered is: " << state[1].statename << " with a population of " << state[1].population << "\n";
    else
        cout << "The most populous state you entered is: " << state[2].statename << " with a population of " << state[2].population << "\n";

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: See my new, updated answer which addresses a few more things you should change.

Comment: The first assignments of `mn` and `mx` seem very wrong. What is the value of  `n` there?

Comment: @MaartenHilferink The assignments are fine. The value of `n` comes from the for loop.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice In the code that I see here, `mn` and `mx` are initialised after the first loop, before the second loop starts, when (the first int) `n` must be 3, which is an out-of-bounds index for `st`.

Comment: @MaartenHilferink ahh...I was looking at the assignments in the if statements in the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to store the name of each state with its population. It will help if you change `title` to `name` to make it more clear what the variable is for. If you do this correctly, you will quickly see that you no longer need `mystr`. (Note that you should always use meaningful variable names. A generic name like `mystr` often means that you do not know the purpose of the variable. Keep thinking about what the variable is for in order to make a more useful name.)

Now once you have the state data input into the array correclty, you should keep track of the data for the least and most populous state, rather than just its population. Instead of

```
int mn, mx;
```

declare

```
state_t mn, mx;
```

Then in your if statement do

```
mn = st[n];
```

and similarly for `mx`.

You will have to change your `if` condition to access the value in the struct. Then you can print the values directly from `mn` and `mx`.

Comment: @KevinHernandez What is `mystr`? What happens when you type the most populous state first and the rest have lower populations?

Comment: It didn't work after I tested what I had commented before. I changed what you said. But I'm not sure how to do my if statements. 
   for (int n = 1; n < 3; n++)
   {
    if (mn > st[n])
    {
     mn = st[n];
     
    }
    if (mx < st[n])
    {
     mx = st[n];
     
    }
   }

Comment: @KevinHernandez then you are doing something wrong. Keep trying.

Comment: Ok I've changed my struct to have

  struct states_t {
   string name;
   int population, mn, mx;
  } st[3];

I changed my if statements to the above, but I get identifier mn is undefined

Comment: Back up a step. What does the struct represent?

Comment: Array size 3 that has members string name, int pop mn and mx

Comment: @KevinHernandez that does not tell me what the data **represents**. What does one individual struct mean? Whay does it stand for?

Comment: Ok, I redid my code and am taking out the biggest number stuff right now to understand it. The way it is I have my struct which as state name and population. It ask use input for name and pop for each state [3] . In the bottom I post the 3 states with their corresponding population. Does all this seem right from here?

Comment: @KevinHernandez that definitely sounds like you are on the right track

Comment: I think I got it now. I may have done it a longer way...
I want to go deeper though. I want to learn how to make the bottom part (largest population) shorter and more efficient... think you can teach me?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is designed to find the highest (and lowest) population of all states. You could also have tried to find out what the index-number is of the state with the highest population and use that number to index the state array to get what you need from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

I would first make two int arrays, one corresponding to the index values of the array of `struct states_t`, and then one corresponding to the population values, like such:

```
int index[3];
int pop[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    index[i] = i;
    pop[i] = st[i].population;
}
```

Next, perform a bubble sort algorithm on the population, and move the indices of the objects around according to the actions of the sort algorithm like such:

```
int n = 3;

for (int i = 0 ; i < ( n - 1 ); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < n - i - 1; j++)
    {
        //if the population of the next element
        //is higher than the current element, swap it
        //perform the same operation for state indices
        if (array[j] > array[j+1]) 
        {
            int swap = pop[j];
            int swap2 = index[j];
            pop[j] = pop[j+1];
            index[j] = index[j+1];
            pop[j+1] = swap;
            index[j+1] = swap2;
        }
    }
}
```

All that's left to do now is to call the first object in the list with the index array like such:

```
st[index[0]].title; //state with highest population
```

Coolest part about this method is that you can make this work for *any* number of States by changing the value of `int n`.

Comment: @KevinHernandez Oh yes, this example still uses the struct mentioned above (which is your data structure), but just uses some different logic and a couple other things to complete the task. Not too sure what you mean by that comment there.

Answer (score 0):

While there is nothing that prevents you from using a standard *array-of-struct* as you would in C, embracing the C++ `std::vector` can take a bulk of the tedium out of it. While using the array-of-struct, you get the benefit of protecting your array bounds manually indexing and manually handling storage, C++ has long sought to help alleviate or ease the manual aspects of handling collections of "things" (for lack of better words)

The [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container is tailor made to allow you to add to a collection of things using the simple `push_back` modifier. Basically you define your `struct` (say `s_state_t`) holding your `name` and `pop`, much as you have, and then declare and create an instance of a `vector` of type `<s_state_t>` (say `state`). Then to add a state (say `s`) to the vector you simply `state.push_back(s)` and let `std::vector` handle the storage and indexing. (`vector` also provides many other helpful member functions and modifiers to help get information about your collection)

Then the C++ way to approach managing a collection of `states` is to create either an additional `struct` or `class` to manipulate your collections of states, to add to, check and keep track of the max/min populations, etc. In a very simple form, you could create a class, that provides member functions that do just that, add a new state, check the max/min and then provide a way to output the contents of your collection. For example, you could do something like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

typedef struct {        /* struct holding state name and population */
    std::string name;
    int pop;
} s_state_t;

class country {         /* class country - a collection of states */ 
    std::vector<s_state_t> state;   /* declare vector for states */
    s_state_t mx = { "", 0 },       /* declare structs for max min */
            mn = { "", std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };
    void chkmxmn (s_state_t s) {    /* function to set max/min */
        if (s.pop < mn.pop)
            mn = s;
        if (s.pop > mx.pop)
            mx = s;    
    }
  public:
    void addstate (std::string name, int pop) { /* add a state */
        s_state_t s = { name, pop };    /* struct for new state */
        chkmxmn (s);                    /* update max and min */
        state.push_back (s);            /* push_back to vector */
    }
    void prnstates() {                  /* output saved states, max/min */
        for (auto& i : state)           /* loop over vector */
            std::cout << std::setw(16) << std::left << i.name << 
                        std::setw(10) << std::right << i.pop << "\n";
        std::cout << "\nminimum and maximum populations:\n" <<
                    std::setw(16) << std::left << mn.name <<
                    std::setw(10) << std::right << mn.pop << "\n" <<
                    std::setw(16) << std::left << mx.name <<
                    std::setw(10) << std::right << mx.pop << "\n";
    }
};

int main (void) {

    country us; /* instance of country */

    us.addstate ("Texas", 25000000);        /* add names/pops */
    us.addstate ("Louisiana", 12000000);
    us.addstate ("California", 50000000);
    us.prnstates(); /* output results */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you should add additional validations to check the `name` is not `NULL` or empty and `pop` is a reasonable number -- that is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/vector_states
Texas             25000000
Louisiana         12000000
California        50000000

minimum and maximum populations:
Louisiana         12000000
California        50000000
```

**note:** you can also create a `typedef` to your new `vector` type to cut down on the typing associated with specifying instances and parameters of the type with something similar to:

```
typedef std::vector<s_state_t> state_t; /* typedef to cut down typing */
```

which then allows you to declare new instances or parameters as simply, e.g.:

```
state_t state;                  /* declare vector for states */
```

Look things over. Neither method is more "right or wrong", but if you are going to learn C++ instead of C, you might as well go ahead and use the nice parts of it.